# How exactly to use and save images in Xamarin(in ListView)?

Tags: image, sqlite, xamarin

i want to be able to take a picture with the emulator, have it create and save an item on the database and display properly on my main Item Page, how do I go about doing this?

i tried my best to only show what is important and related to this and therefore have cut a bunch of stuff out(for example my View for adding items isnt present because i THINK the only part relating to this is the button with a command binding to it leading to the viewmodel)

the reason im asking here is because there are no errors showing, the application doesnt start at all like this and im really confused, i appreciate any and all help and thank you in advance.

*if you need any additional info about anything related to this please do ask and i will share it as soon as i see your messeage.*

my Item.cs

```
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string LongDescription { get; set; }
        public MediaFile Image { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfQuantity { get; set; }
    }
```

my main page Listview (without the unimportant parts in XAML)

```
<ListView>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Item">
               <ViewCell Height="220" xct1:ShadowEffect.Radius="5">
                   <Grid Padding="7">
                       <Frame CornerRadius="15">
                           <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                             
                                      ...// bunch of labels and what not//
                               </StackLayout>
                           </StackLayout>
                       </Frame>
                   </Grid>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

the Item Creating ViewModel (unrelated things cut out)

```
public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShDesc { get; set; }
        public string LgDesc { get; set; }
        public string Qty { get; set; }
        public MediaFile Image { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfQty { get; set; }
        public AsyncCommand AddCommand { get; }
        public AsyncCommand PicCommand { get; }
        public ItemAddViewModel()
        {
            AddCommand = new AsyncCommand(Add);
            PicCommand = new AsyncCommand(Pic);
        }
        async Task Add()
        {
            var name = Name;
            var description = ShDesc;
            var longdescription = LgDesc;
            var qty = Qty;
            var typeofqty = TypeOfQty;
            var image = Image;
            await ItemService.AddItem(name, description, longdescription, qty, typeofqty, image);
            Name = ShDesc = LgDesc = Qty = TypeOfQty = null;

        }
        async Task Pic()
        {
            var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
                  new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                  {
                      SaveToAlbum = true
                  });
            Image = photo;
        }
    }
}
```

my Services and DB

```
 public static class ItemService
    {
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
        static async Task Init()
        {
            //creats Database if it doesnt exist
            if (db != null)
                return; 

            var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Mydata.db");
            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);

            await db.CreateTableAsync<Item>();
        }
        //adds item to database
       public static async Task AddItem(string Name, string Description,string LongDescription, string Quantity, string TypeOfQuantity, MediaFile image)
        {
            await Init();
            var item = new Item
            {
                Name = Name,
                LongDescription = LongDescription,
                Description = Description,
                Quantity = Quantity,
                TypeOfQuantity = TypeOfQuantity,
                Image = image
            };
            await db.InsertAsync(item);

        }
```

Comment: you need to start by figuring out why the app doesn't start.  Look at the build log, the deployment log, the device log, etc.  Debugging your code is pointless if the app won't even start.

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a basic, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to Github and attach the link here.

Comment: i think this is what i was supposed to do, i cut out everything that wasnt related (i think) i will provide anything else if need be https://github.com/MomchilSim/XamApp

Comment: I will try and give U a feedback on it.